# Facebook Login Modal View Not Dismissed

Tags: ios6, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, modalviewcontroller, facebook-login

I am having issues dismissing my modal view after the app has returned from the facebook login.  I have followed the facebook tutorial and made some liberties to the code as I did not want to use the app delegate.  I'l post some code snippets

I am using two classes.  One class is my initial view that pops up if a user had been logged in called DayViewController and then my modal view that pops up if a user isn't logged in.  LoginViewController.

Should also be noted that I am using storyboards and I built my app so that DayViewController has a nav bar embeded in it and that is then embeded in the tab bar.  I think my issue is in the facebook tutorial they use some code to get the view that is currently displayed and then dismiss that...I haven't been able to implement that.

DayViewController  Class--

ViewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    if (FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded) {
        [self openSession];
}else {
    [self showLoginView];
}
   [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

showLoginView

```
- (void)showLoginView{

UIViewController *topViewController = [self.navigationController topViewController];
UIViewController *modalViewController = [topViewController presentedViewController];

if (![modalViewController isKindOfClass:[LoginViewController class]]) {


    LoginViewController *lvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"loginView"];
    [self presentViewController:lvc animated:NO completion:nil];

} else {
    LoginViewController *loginVC = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];
    [loginVC loginFailed];
}
}
```

sessionStateChanged

```
- (void)sessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session
                  state:(FBSessionState) state
                  error:(NSError *)error
{
switch (state) {
    case FBSessionStateOpen: {

        UIViewController *topViewController =  [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"loginView"];



        //LoginViewController *lvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"loginView"];

        if ([[topViewController presentedViewController]
             isKindOfClass:[LoginViewController class]]) {
            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];

        }else{
        }
    }
        break;
    case FBSessionStateClosed:

    case FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed:
        // Once the user has logged in, we want them to
        // be looking at the root view.
        //[self.navController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];

        [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];

        [self showLoginView];


        break;
    default:

        break;
}

if (error) {
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                              initWithTitle:@"Error"
                              message:error.localizedDescription
                              delegate:nil
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
    NSLog(@"Error");
    [alertView show];
}
}
```

Default OpenSession

```
- (void)openSession{
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:nil allowLoginUI:YES completionHandler: ^(FBSession *session,FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
     [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
 }];
}
```

LoginViewController  Class---

Nothing dramatic in this class, only a sign-in button that throws the facebook states through the openSession function

```
- (IBAction)signInButton:(id)sender {
[self.loginActivityIndicator startAnimating];
dvc = [[DayViewController alloc] init];
[dvc openSession];

//[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];
}
```

Comment: Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? I'm having a similar issue.